# csv - take away data of one column from another

Tags: python, csv

I want to take the value of column 4 from column 3 (their both integers), this is what I have.

```
with open('CLASSES.csv', 'rt')as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    people=[]
    for column in reader:
        people.append(column[0:8])

difference = [x[3] for x in people] - [x[4] for x in people]
print(difference)
```

I get the error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'** when this. I know why I get the error but I can't think of a way around it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: `difference = [x[3] - x[4] for x in people]`

Comment: **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'** is the error I get when using that coding @PeterWood

Comment: You have strings you need to convert to integers: `int(x[3]) - int(x[4])`

Comment: okay thank you, sorry I'm new as you can tell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Peter Wood said in the comment, you need to subtract inside of one list comprehension, not doing two list comprehension as this results in `list - list`.
Also you need to convert to numbers.

```
difference = [int(x[3]) - int(x[4]) for x in people]
```

If you want to do stuff like this, you are probably better off using `numpy` or even `pandas`.

Using numpy and it's `genfromtxt` function:

```
import numpy as np
people = np.genfromtxt('CLASSES.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None)
difference = people[:, 3] - people[:, 4]
```

Here `people` will be a two dimensional numpy array, this first index going over the rows, second over the columns `[:, 3]` takes every row of the thirds column.

The `dtype=None` option lets `genfromtxt` automatically decide the type for each column, default is `float`.